# SEO Audit - Get Google Indexed Pages Count

Tags: php, search-engine, google-search

I have a problem with the construction of an SEO Audit.

On a page, i created one input, which is "Site URL".

When we start an Audit, i want to crawl and show the number of Google Indexed pages. (Ex : Display "You have 'X' indexed pages on Google).

When we do it for ourselves, we can just use the Google Search Console, or site:www.site.com.

In 2014, that was something like this :

```
$ip = $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"];
$url = get_domain($url);
$result = json_decode(@file_get_contents("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:$url&filter=0&gl=fr&userip=$ip"));
```

Now, ajax googleapis is deprecated, and I didn't find the new solution with Google Search Engine.

If anybody has the answer, i'm waiting, because i can't find it alone, make me mad.

Thanks for future answers !

Adri.